# Get info from another page into javascript

Tags: javascript, php

For now, I have a code in javascript to get a song title.
I need to change the script. The new server is not supporting javascript anymore.

I have a link where only the current song is showing.
But how can I get that into a javascript file?

http://blaffdf.nl/songtitle.php

Info on `songtitle.php` page (do I need a js script?).

```
 var str = StreamInformation.SONGTITLE();

 var str = $infoofphpfile;
```

Who can help me?

Many thanx!

Comment: `The new server is not supporting javascript anymore.`-> what do you mean?

Comment: Javascript is run on the browser! Unless you are using something like `node.js`

Comment: @RiggsFolly The page is refreshing every 2 minutes. So i only need to get the text from php into the js file.

Comment: fetch('/pathtoyourserverendpoint/songtitle')

Comment: You need to use AJAX, either using `XMLHttpRequest` object or using new `fetch` function.

Comment: I have JSON api on remote location.

"songtitle":"Live with the music station on the internet"

How i include these remote page? example.com/stats?json=1 

var str = songtitle